# How to redirect if the header is been sent?

Tags: php, redirect

I use wordpress and unfortunately, I have to work behind the backend. I need to print message about user action while the CMS header has been sent.

Is there any alternative than using javascript? I prefer a PHP solution.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "'. $redirect_url . '";'; 
echo '/* ]]> */</script>';
```

Comment: to redirect or to print a message?

Comment: @col. sharper : to redirect then print the message based on user acion (for example, deleting image, adding image, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the message by using query string:

```
header('location: index.php?msg=1');exit;
```

And use swich to show the message based on value of `msg` query string var:

```
switch($_GET['msg'])
{
   case: 1; // do foo
   case: 2; // do bar
   case else : ; // ooops
}
```

Comment: He said after the header has been sent... I presume he meant once the content has been started - php will complain if you try send a header again

Answer (score 1):

You can't undo that header sending ... but you can buffer it, which is what I ended up doing when I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279864/php-output-buffering-whats-the-best-practise).

Hope that helps

Comment: from behind of that noted "backend"?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:

1.) place **config.php** to load at the top of every page and put **ob_start** in it

2.) place **end_load.php** to load at the end of every page and put the **ob_end** in it

this way will ensure no output is given to client till the end of processing and you can use header redirect at any time of page.

i am ignorant of disadvantages of it. May be caching has disadvantage but not sure

Comment: @downvoter: plz write something as i can also know why its not good

Comment: I voted you back up (not down) & would like to know the disadvantage too; it seems fine to me.