# Redirect non-javascript users when headers have been sent

Tags: php

I want to redirect a user where one of condition is true, but I cannot easy write `header('Location : something');`, because in my case headers have already been sent (HTML content has been displayed). I know that if user has enabled JavaScript I can write something like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.location.href = "http://google.pl";
</script>
```

But I want to redirect **every users**, include that which haven't gov JS enabled. I add that this situation is in the `<body>` section of document. Is there any way to do that ? I'm asking for every solutions, they must be not for PHP.

PS I read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412806/how-to-rediect-if-the-header-is-been-sent) article, but I think that it cannot help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by [cleaning output buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) using `ob_end_clean();` function and then use PHP `header();`. Of course on the start of the document I have written `ob_start();` and on the end `ob_end_flush();`. You can read more about output buffering [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Answer (score 3):

Make use of **`<noscript>`** tag.

Something like this

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/somepage.html" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: Yes, ok but my <head> section has been shown, now I cannot use it.

Comment: @Ty221, I don't get you. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: I have shown my <head> section of HTML document. Metatags can be only added into the <head> section.

Comment: What is the problem in adding this code on your `<head>` section ?

Comment: Because then I will have to totally change the logic of my program.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible, i think so. but you can implement a message for the browser says to the user that he/she should activate javascript.

```
<noscript>
    You can browse this site without having JavaScript enabled,
    but to experience the full benefits of the site, please enable JavaScript.
</noscript>
```

But you can move forward with the **php** solution itself.

Add

```
ob_start()
```

at the start of the php page and then use

```
header('Location : something');
```

I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of redirecting non-Javascript users Redirect Javascript Users**

first give the user the page should be redirected if the user disabled the javascript.

there you write the javascript to redirect the user to the page if the user enabled the javascript, so if the user enabled the javascript then he will be redirected to the correct page but if he disabled the javascript the script not works and he stays in the page which actually should be redirected... hope this useful....