# Output buffer, get contents after processing?

Tags: php

I am using output buffering to process stuff (very descriptive, I know).

What I'd like to do is cause output buffering to end, have the handler functions perform their processing, and then get the resulting output as a string, *not* output to the browser.

Is this possible? I can't seem to work out what combination of `ob_end`/`ob_get` functions I would need to achieve this... and my initial thought of "I can just buffer the output of `ob_end_flush`" is... well, absurd :p

---

As a basic example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?php
ob_start(function($c) {return "PASS\n";});
echo "FAIL\n";
$c = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_flush(); // outputs PASS, as it has been processed
echo $c; // outputs FAIL, because that was the content of the buffer... unprocessed...
// I want it processed.
```

Comment: Reopening as not a duplicate of [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279864/php-output-buffering-whats-the-best-practise?lq=1).

Comment: Care to provide provide more info to your actual question instead of as a comment under an answer?

Comment: Is that better @PeeHaa?

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to get the current buffer, post-processed rather than pre-processed (which is what `ob_get_contents` gives). I have implemented a workaround in the form of another layer of output buffering around the whole thing, but it's a bit messy!

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue now with the edits and comments.  You are correct that you'll need another output buffer since the callback is only called when flush or end is called and before any get in the function:

```
ob_start(function($c) {return "PASS\n";});
echo "FAIL\n";
ob_start();
ob_end_flush(); // buffers PASS, as it has been processed
$c = ob_get_contents();
echo $c; // outputs PASS
```

Comment: My understanding of `ob_get_contents()` is that it returns the contents of the buffer, which would be *before* the handler has run. [See this IDEOne example](https://ideone.com/390ikd) - I would expect `PASS` twice but I get `PASS/FAIL`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why do you expect `PASS` twice ? You only flush the buffer once, so the callback also only gets called once.

Comment: "Expect" was the wrong word. I mean that's what I "want" to happen - ie. getting the contents of the buffer *after* processing has happened, without it being dumped to the browser.

Comment: `ob_get_contents()` gets `FAIL` and `ob_end_flush()` get `PASS` from callback and echoes it.  Then you echo `FAIL` from `$c`.  So you get `PASS FAIL`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol TBH with you I don't really see what your question is/ what you would expect as output and why. You turn on output buffering with a callback with `ob_start()` (Means every time you flush the buffer the callback gets called). Then you print "FAIL" in the buffer. Then you get the buffer content into a variable with `ob_get_contents()` (Note: You don't flush the buffer here). After this you end the buffer AND flush it with `ob_end_flush()`. Which will print: `PASS`. And at the end you also print the buffer content which you stored in `$o`, which is `FAIL`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I think now you messed something in your code up :) You started 2x output buffering, but only ended one, so all echo's further down in the code wouldn't be printed, since you never ended the first ob_start(); See: http://3v4l.org/DYaQT

Comment: Yes, I was just showing how to get at the first one.  I should have left this question alone :-(

Comment: @AbraCadaver I also don't really see what OP wants. And If I would have to poker, I would guess something in this direction: `ob_start(function($c) {return "PASS\n";});
  echo "FAIL\n";
  ob_flush();
  $c = ob_get_contents();
  
  ob_end_flush();
  var_dump($c);` So that he flush's the buffer twice and gets 2x "PASS" and never FAIL, since he flushed the buffer before he gets the content from the buffer